# I want make this curve in the container

Tags: flutter, containers

This image show what I want to do ,, I used container and made border radius to bottom right and this is ok , but in bottom left I don’t know how to make this curve [image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177462/flutter-make-resizeable-parts-of-customclipper/63216703#63216703

Comment: What you are seeing is a complex shape made with a customPainter and probably has a Container widget with top left circular corner  stacked above that custom painter. https://www.raywenderlich.com/7560981-drawing-custom-shapes-with-custompainter-in-flutter refer this link for basic of custom painter or watch tutorial videos on customPainter and Stack widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it using CustomPainter.
Please check the following example.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: CurvePainterPage(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurvePainterPage extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.blue[800];
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height * .70);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        0, size.height * .60, size.width * .1565, size.height * .60);
    path.lineTo(size.width * .60, size.height * .60);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .69, size.height * .60,
        size.width * .70, size.height * .50);
    path.lineTo(size.width * .70, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image]

You can read about it more [here](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-draw-custom-shapes-in-flutter-aa197bda94bf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BoxDecoration` inside the Container.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    color: Colors.white,),
    child:Text(
      'Greetings, planet!',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Colors.grey[300],
      ),))
```